# SWF building through API

Tags: flash-cs5

I want to build my project by using a custom program. Does the Flash Professional CS5 give support to some API that i can use to build the FLA project from outside the IDE to build the project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use JSFL scripts to send open and build commands to Flash Professional, but you'll need to have it installed, and there is no commandline compiler, each script will be run by the IDE itself.